# Using regular expressions in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I want to compare 2 arrays by matching/replacing elements of array 2 found in array 1 with elements of array 3. The issue is that the elements containing (\d+) can't be found and replaced in array1 despite and it should. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
var array1 = [" Jane's number is 7788 ", " Michael ran 8 miles ", " MIchael was 8 km from Jane ", ...]
var txt_extracts = [ " number is (\d+) ", " (\d+) miles ", " Michael ran ", ...]
var txt_extracts2 = [" ! ", " @ ", " ? ", ...]

var y = 1;
txt_extracts.forEach(myfunction2);


function myfunction2(item2, index_number) {
 var re2 = new RegExp(item2,"gi");
var search_status2 = array1[y-1].search(re2);
if (search_status2 > -1)
{
alert("match found");
array1[y] = array1[y-1].replace(re2, txt_extracts2[index_number]);
y++
alert(array1[y]);
}
}
```

Comment: Please _rephrase_ your question by instead showing sample inputs, along with what you wish to extract/capture from those inputs.

Comment: I did not test the code, but note that when you use new RegExp that you have to double escape `\\d+`